# how can i render a react Prompt in a specific URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i need to render this prompt but only when the next url doesn't begin with /calendar/
I tried with window.location.pathname but this only gets the current URL, i need to know the next URL in order to know if i must render or not this prompt, i dont want the prompt gets rendered when URL change from "/calendar/" to "/calendar/information" because it's still the same page

```js
<Prompt
  when={(this.props.agendaPlaces.length >=3 && this.props.users.length === 0)}//
  message={JSON.stringify({
    language: this.props.i18n.language,
    header: t('userLeaveConfirmationTitle'), 
    header2: t('userLeaveConfirmationTitle2'), 
    content:t('userLeaveConfirmationBody'),
    confirm:t('userLeaveConfirmationConfirm'),
    cancel:t('userLeaveConfirmationCancel')
  })}
/>
```

Comment: Put it inside a route with `path="/calendar/"` and `exact`?

Comment: Check the [official docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt) for a pretty good example using the `location`.

Comment: Would this help?
`window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] !== 'calendar'`

Comment: that doesn't work because it's the same url, i need to know the URL is going to be render, i tried your suggest and it works the same as if it weren't

Comment: i came up with the answer it seems that there is a param in prompt called location, it takes the url that calls the prompt, not like window.location that takes the current url `<Prompt
            when={(this.props.agendaPlaces.length >=3 && this.props.users.length === 0)}//
            message={(location)=>{
                return location.pathname.startsWith("/calendar/")?true:"message"
            })}} /> `